# how to use microsoft undname utility

Tags: dll

I am trying to do reverse engineering on dll.

how to use undname utility on functions that are retrieved using dumpbin utility?

how can i run undname on functions please let me know

Comment: Did you read any documentation?  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: by dumpbin i am able to get function names.. but in order to run undname on functions to get parameter type.. how can i run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to pass the decorated name on the command line.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx) has this example:

```
C:\>undname ?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1981-2000. All rights reserved.Undecoration
of :- "?func1@a@@AAEXH@Z"
is :- "private: void __thiscall a::func1(int)"
```

Comment: how to get decorated name ? by using dumpbin i am able to get function names of dll which is not useful. we can run dumpbin with /symbols to get decorated names for lib and obj files. but i have only dll. how can i get decorated names from dll using dumpbin is it possible?