# Redirecting mangled functions via DLL proxying

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, reverse-engineering

I'm fiddling around with an old game and am trying to learn how it works. My current experiments include trying to proxy one of the game's DLL.

So I renamed the original `DLL.dll` to `trueDLL.dll`, dumped the DLL's exports with `dumpbin` and created the `#pragma`s (fine for now, I'll look into .def files later) to generate an "empty" proxy. This worked as expected.

Now, I'd like to redirect some of the functions to my reverse engineered implementations to test if they work. This is where I got stuck. Here's an example: the `LogDebug` function. The "empty", working pragma in the proxy DLL look like this:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?LogDebug@@YAXPBDZZ=trueDLL.?LogDebug@@YAXPBDZZ,@504")
```

I thought I could change the pragma like so to redirect the call to my implementation:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:?LogDebug@@YAXPBDZZ=LogInfo,@504")
```

Running the program, it fails to start because it can't find `?LogDebug@@YAXPBDZZ`. Some research shows that the `@@YAXPBDZZ` part isn't exported in my DLL. It appears to be some kind of info represented in the mangled name, but I couldn't find out what it actually means. Ghidra and [this demangler](https://demangler.com/) aren't helping either, and the only search results are in russian.

Using VS 2019, no project settings are altered.

What is the problem here and how would I go about making this work? Or is there an easier/better way of achieving this? I'd like to avoid hooking the calls in the program exe for now but if I have to, I'll do it.

#### EDIT - Mangling scheme and compiler

I don't know exactly what was used to create `DLL.dll`, but according to Ghidra it was `visualstudio:unknown`. I'd interpret that as a 1998 (game file dates) version of MSVC. I'm using the current MSVC compiler (`CL` ver. 19).

It'd make sense for a current `CL` to use the C++ scheme. Looking at [this page](https://en.m.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling), and comparing it to the exports, `DLL.dll` appears to be using the C++ scheme too, but I could be wrong. How do I find this out for sure?

Comment: What name mangling scheme does `DLL.dll` use? What name mangling scheme does your replacement library use? `"C"`? `"C++"`? In the latter case, which compiler?

Comment: There are diffent schemes? I'll update the question to add what I know.

Comment: The "default" has actually always been `"C"`. It's the only sane name mangling that stands a chance of surviving a compiler update. `"C++"` name mangling is just wild, and every compiler invents its very own name decoration scheme. If you are having difficulty finding out what name decoration scheme is being used, post one of the original exports.

Comment: Original DLL `dumpbin /exports`: https://pastebin.com/mc6fsKTz

Comment: Use the [undname.exe utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947299/how-to-use-microsoft-undname-utility) from the developer command prompt.  Shows you that you'll have to write a C++ function with the signature void __cdecl LogDebug(char const *,... ) {} to keep the linker happy.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact signature of my `LogDebug` implementation. Links just fine, but the program crashes with the error being the one in the question. `dumpbin` reveals the export of my DLL to be `505  1F8 000112FD ?LogInfo = @ILT+760(?LogInfo@@YAXPBDZZ)`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the method in my DLL doesn't need the `#pragma`, as it actually overwrites the desired behaviour. If I define my function like `undname.exe` says and just add a `__declspec(dllexport)` in front, everything falls into place nicely.

Comment: You may want to consider being more explicit here by providing a [language linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage), i.e. `extern "C++"`. This prevents you from accidentally compiling the code with a C compiler.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks!